# Friend wants to put me on his insurance, how can this bite me in the ass if we get into an accident?

Tags: traffic, vehicle, washington, motor-vehicle

UNITED STATES, WASHINGTON STATE, PIERCE COUNTY, TACOMA CITY

I have a house mate who is disabled due to a stroke and cannot drive his car. He suggested to me that I can drive his car and in return i can use the car to get groceries. He said that he wants to put me on his insurance and that he would need my full name and a copy of my drivers license. I told him I would think about it.

Could this cause me any problems if things go wrong? For instance if we get into an accident? My license is fine, it's active, current, and not suspended or revoked. I just want to ask if it is legal for me to use his car with his permission if I were to use it to get groceries when he is not in the car with me.

Comment: I've edited your post to fix the punctuation and capitalization. In future please consider that you are asking people to take time to help with your problem. The least you can do in return is take the care and time to make your post as easy to read as possible. I've also tweaked the wording in a couple of places; if I've misunderstood then do change those bits back.

Answer (score 3):

You always run some legal risk when you drive. As long as you are insured (you have a card in your hand) and you have permission to drive the car, it does not matter who owns the car. There is a difference between the legal minimum insurance coverage and actually adequate coverage, and since you are not getting separate insurance where control the insurance levels, you theoretically run some liability risk if you have an accident and the coverage is less than the damages (insurance doesn't mean that the other guy can't take you to court for the rest of the amount).

There is also a risk that the housemate will do something crazy like cancel the insurance coverage for you, or report the car stolen, so you have to decide how worried you are about that possibility.